# "Proper" way to recreate undocumented structs / classes given memory layout in C++?

Tags: x86, c++

Firstly I acknowledge that this is very borderline opinionated, but I'd like to emphasize this is more a thing of possibilities given some shortcomings of the default just writing down the offsets of things.

I do a lot of reverse engineering and then I write C/C++ code to mess with what I've learned. Suppose there is a class like this, representing a monster:

```
OFFSET  SIZE    VALUE
0       8       Pointer to methods
1280    4       X coordinate
1284    4       Y coordinate
128C    4       Z coordinate
1400    4       Health
```

where, for example, `*(float*)((uint8_t*)obj + 0x1280)` would give the X coordinate. The rest of the class is unknown, and the only known method is `*(uint32_t*)((uint8_t*)*(uint32_t*)obj + 0xC)`, which just sets the health.

These kinds of classes can be updated very frequently, making it incredibly annoying to just have recorded the offsets of different things. I have seen it suggested to create a padded class with just `uint8_t[next off - start]`, but even that just feels really awkward.

Right now the best thing I can think of to do would be to create a bunch of different bytescans (excluding the offsets) for different methods of the object that access its members and automatically determine the offsets, but still.

My problem is that although I don't actually mind the updating itself, my code looks *terrible*. I effectively treat these objects as just integers floating around and have a bunch of scattered functions that operate on them like objects, but really they aren't.

Is there a "proper" way to define an object with "suggested" offsets, with or without llibraries, and regardless, what would be a decent way to have clean code working with undocumented and mostly unknown objects like these?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a struct of pointers and initialise them at run time.  In some cases it might also be possible to alias to arrays.

If using a padded struct, be careful of compiler alignment of the fields.